# Scrapy and Selenium: Make scrapy wait for selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a spider that I am using to crawl a site. I only need javascript for one piece of my item.  So I scrape part of the site with scrapy then open the URL in selenium. While the URL is opening scrapy continues. How do I make scrapy to wait on my selenium logic to finish?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm looking into what signals I can give selenium when things are done and then execute on signal if anybody has any guidance. Thx

Comment: What page are you trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25** in settings.py,that the downloader should wait before downloading consecutive pages from the same website.

Another way you can use **time.sleep()**  for delaying spider to get response from selenium.